# NHibernate SQLFunction group by

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, group-by, queryover

I am trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT round(song.rating), count(song.song_id) FROM song
GROUP BY round(song.rating);
```

My QueryOver:

```
 var output = sess.QueryOver<song>()
                .SelectList(list => list
                    .Select(Projections.SqlFunction("round", NHibernateUtil.Int32, Projections.GroupProperty("rating")))
                    .SelectCount(s => s.song_id))
                .List<object[]>()
                .Select(prop => new RatingStat
                {
                    rating = (int)prop[0],
                    count = (int)prop[1]
                }).ToList<RatingStat>();
```

Expected output:

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|                         0 |                        12 |
|                         1 |                         1 |
|                         3 |                         1 |
|                         4 |                         6 |
|                         5 |                         3 |
|                         6 |                         6 |
|                         7 |                        12 |
|                         8 |                         7 |
|                         9 |                         9 |
|                        10 |                         2 |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Actual output:

```
0                         12
1                         1
3                         1
4                         1
4                         3
4                         1
4                         1
5                         1
5                         1
5                         1
6                         2
6                         1
6                         3
7                         2
7                         9
7                         1
8                         1
8                         3
8                         2
8                         1
9                         1
9                         3
9                         1
9                         4
10                        2
```

I am using my own dialect inherited from MySQL5Dialect, because my MySQL dialect doesnt support round function.
Here is how round function is defined in my dialect:

```
 RegisterFunction("round", new StandardSafeSQLFunction("round", NHibernateUtil.Int32,1));
```

My question is, why do I have multiple groups of same rating value? Rounded values should be distinct. Is it possible that round function doesnt work correctly?
Edit: added genetated SQL statement

```
 SELECT round(this_.rating) as y0_, count(this_.song_ID) as y1_ FROM song this_ GROUP BY this_.rating
```

Comment: I know this is probably a stupid comment but what is your actual generated SQL statement as it looks like its not applying the group by properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found solution:

```
 var t = Projections.SqlFunction("round", NHibernateUtil.Int32, Projections.GroupProperty("rating"));
 var output = sess.QueryOver<Song>()
       .SelectList(list => list
       .Select(Projections.SqlFunction("round", NHibernateUtil.Int32, Projections.GroupProperty(t)))
       .SelectCount(s => s.song_id))
       .List<object[]>()
       .Select(prop => new RatingStat
        {
            rating = (int)prop[0],
            count = (int)prop[1]
        }).ToList<RatingStat>();
```